# Ratio involving CDF and PDF of a standard normal random variable behaves unexpected when plotted

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Good morning,

I am plotting the function $h[x]$, see below, and obtain an oscillating behavior in the range $x \in [7.2,8.3]$ that cannot be explained by the function itself. Also for $x \ge 8.4$ it seems to be a constant function which is not plausible either, and the limit for $x \to \infty$ should be $-1$ and not $0.5$ as visually indicated.

Here is the code:

```
h[x_]:=(x*CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]*Log[CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]])/PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];  Plot[h[x], {x, -7, 20}]
```

There seems to be a numerical issue that I cannot resolve. Do you have any idea?
Thanks for your support,
Aronas.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you boost the Working precision.

```
h[x_] := (x*CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]*
    Log[CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]])/
  PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
```

Then

```
Plot[h[x], {x, -5, 14}, WorkingPrecision -> 80]
```

[image]

Note that for a  `WorkingPrecision -> 40` one gets a smooth output with a sharp discontinuity near 13.5 which is somewhat misleading.

Comment: Thanks chris for the very fast answer!! It works here as well. Have a nice day, Aronas.

Comment: You are welcome. Please don't forget to  eventually validate the answer which best address your problem .